# Bridged mode does not present network address, but instead 10.0.2.15/24

Tags: virtualbox, bridge

Host OS: Windows 11

Guest: GNU/Linux Debian 11

Versión VirtualBox: Versión 7.0.6 r155176 (Qt5.15.2)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did a reboot to the machine and it shows me the ip.

Comment: This isn't about managing IT in a business environment. I suggest using superuser.com for this question.